# Set date from PHP variable to daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to set date from PHP variable (because values are coming from the database) to daterangepicker but it's not working and it's setting the today's date

Code

```
<?php $start_date = "04-07-2021"; ?>
<?php $end_date = "10-07-2021"; ?>
<input type="text" name="date-range">
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start_date = <?php echo $start_date; ?>;
    var end_date = <?php echo $end_date; ?>;
    $('input[name="date-range"]').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start_date,
        endDate: end_date,
        locale: {
          format: 'DD-MM-YYYY'
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your dates are strings so you need to put them in quotes when you turn them into JS string literals:

```
var start_date = "<?php echo $start_date; ?>";
var end_date = "<?php echo $end_date; ?>";
```

If you don't, they'll be incomprehensible to the JS interpreter and cause a syntax error (which should have been visible in your browser's Console, although you didn't mention it).

Comment: It might not cause a syntax error since it probably sees it as mathematical expressions (type juggling `04` into `4` etc. It's JS after all).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ah that's true, it might. Also just occurred to me this might not be the end of the story for the OP either depending if their datepicker understands dd-mm-yyyy dates or not

Comment: @ADyson That works but when I tried putting `$data['startdate']` this is coming from the DB, it's not working setting different date and also daterangepicker coming with NaN

Comment: Well have you checked what the content of `$data['startdate']` actually is in the case(s) where it doesn't work? We can't see that, there's not much we can do to help you without more details

Comment: @ADyson Yes it's a date which I mentioned in the question, if I do echo it's coming `10-04-2020`

Comment: @Thor, the answer above by ADyson should be working, provided that the date data is in correct format DD-MM-YYYY. (So if your data comes from a db please make sure the format is correct and no spaces before and after the data).

Comment: So you're saying that `10-07-2021` works but `10-04-2020` doesn't? What happens if you hard-code `10-04-2020` into the text instead?

Comment: @ADyson Yes hard code works but not that dynamic data which I am passing

Comment: Well then that suggests that the dynamic data doesn't really contain exactly what you think it does. Take note of Ken Lee's suggestion and check it for inconsistencies